# Google Analytics stopped tracking

Tags: 7, google-analytics

The [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module on a brand new Drupal 7 build just stopped tracking after 7 days. When I went to investigate, I checked the settings, all appeared fine. Then I checked the source of the page, and the analytics code was nowhere to be seen.

For now I have just added in the javascript within html.tpl.php. But I am curious why it has just stopped working for no apparent reason? A bug with the module?

This site is using a custom theme. I checked the html.tpl.php and `$header` and `$page_bottom` variables were all there.

Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any current bugs like this in the issue queue of the module. So let's check the following:

- What's up with the theme you're using? Have you tried this with another theme?
- What performance settings do you use? (Is Javascript aggregation enabled? Do you use page caching?)
- Is the Analytics code missing from the output when you're logged in as user 1? (If it's there, what's happened with the permissions of the module?)

Comment: Try all of this. Make sure (duh) that Google Analytics module is actually enabled. Install devel module and run `dpm($vars)` on hook_preprocess_html in your theme's template.php. If you still don't see any output from analytics, delete your module and grab a fresh copy. If it's still not outputting, throw some dpm()'s in the google_analytics.module and see what's not getting run or what's not adding the JS.